# JSF: where is proper place to put xml namespaces?

Tags: xml, html, jsf

I've seen two ways to specify xml namespaces: (1)  `<html xmlns:x="...">` , and (2) `<ui:composition xmlns:x="...">`. And in some cases, the page that has the `<html>` tag with namespaces specified, is a JSF template that is referenced by a `<ui:composition template=...>` tag that also specifies those same namespaces (`<ui:composition template="..." xmlns:x="..."`) -- which looks to me like a duplication -- unless, perhaps, the template is used by other `<ui:composition>`'s that don't define the namespaces.

So, I'm wondering what is the "best practice" to specify the xml namespaces (JSF2.2, HTML5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates and their clients are supposed to be independent (as far as it's possible) so just declare what each page needs (master template or template client) at the top of it, even it produces a namespace collision between master template and template clients. In that case, JSF will handle that in order to avoid duplicating the declarations. Also keep in mind that **namespace delarations are only usable for the current template**, not the included clients.

That way, if one day you decide to change your main template (or even bring your template clients to a project which has an unmodifiable master template) your template clients (which can be hundreds depending on the size of the project) won't need to be refactored (possibly they'll need to, but not for **namespaces**).

You'll find [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9435574/1199132) also useful.